# How to parse this time string with Datatables and moment.js?

Tags: datatables, momentjs

So I'm using datatables and their moment.js plugin (https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime). I always get (the string) "Invalid date" returned...

```
{ "data": "last_updated", //source: 2016-11-02 10:32pm GMT
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'YY-MM-DD hh:mmtt GMT', 'DD MMM YY' )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is an "invalid date"?

Comment: Oh sorry: The return I get is: "Invalid date" - It is the default output when moment js can't parse the input.

Comment: Your input/source probably isn't what you expect it is

Comment: It's definitely like this or similar: 2016-11-02 10:32pm GMT It's a string from a MySQL DB.

Comment: Your "From" date format isn't right.
It should be "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmtt GMT".
If this isn't working then remove the GMT from the string.

Answer (score 3):

That plugin takes one, two or three arguments. From testing it seems as though your date is valid so I'd suggest just passing "SS MMM YY" to the function. As a quick example this seems to work:

```
moment("2016-11-02 10:32pm GMT").format("DD MMM YY"); // "02 Nov 16"
```

Another issue might be that the date isn't set, so it's perhaps worth checking for nulls and setting some default content. In fact, if you've already got momentjs available you can replace the plugin with this as the render function:

```
"render": function(data){
    return (moment(data).isValid()) ? moment(data).format("DD MMM YY") : "-";
}
```

Hope that helps.